# JavaFX: How do I override the hashCode method for a bean with properties?

Tags: java, javafx, equals, hashcode

It is common knowledge that when `equals()` is overridden, `hashCode()` must also be overridden.

This is a typical example of this in a non-JavaFX bean class.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + age;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (!(obj instanceof Person))
            return false;
        if (obj == this)
            return true;

        Person rhs = (Person) obj;

        return Objects.equals(name, rhs.name) &&
               age == rhs.age;
    }
}
```

The JavaFX bean:

```
public class Person {
    private StringProperty name;
    private IntegerProperty age;

    // Option A
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + age.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    // Option B
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;
        result = 31 * result + name.get().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + age.get().hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (!(obj instanceof Person))
            return false;
        if (obj == this)
            return true;

        Person rhs = (Person) obj;

        return Objects.equals(name.get(), rhs.name.get()) &&
               Objects.equals(age.get(), rhs.age.get());
    }
}
```

So which of the 2 methods is the correct way to write `hashCode()`? Or is the correct method something totally different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties don't override `hashCode` and `equals`. You can verify this by going to their documentation page (for example [`StringProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/StringProperty.html)) and scrolling down to where it says "Methods inherited from class `java.lang.Object`". If `hashCode` and `equals` are listed, then they aren't overridden.

Because of that, `name.get().hashCode()` would be correct, for example. `name.hashCode()` would return the identity hash code defined by `Object`.

The same can be said for `equals`. For example, `name.equals(rhs.name)` would call the base implementation from `Object`, which is the same as `name == rhs.name`.

Comment: I think that reasoning definitely sounds convincing enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

method hashCode() is to help computer know two objects is not equal quickly, two method you write above is ok.
if you use java 1.7+, you can use

```
Objects.hash(filed1,filed2,filed3,.....)
```

to simplify.